# Can you STOP a PHP namespace reference after a USE?

Tags: php, namespaces

Namespaces are a foreign country to me. I understand the concept but cannot get a handle on the usage.

The only place I am having to use them is to access classes from Twilio and Carbon. For these I have hacked solutions together that seem to work robustly. I am now in a situation where I am worried about a "clash".

For example I use:

```
require_once "../plugins/Twilio/autoload.php";
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
```

to send text messages.

But I also have a `client` variable.

I have had a couple of apparent "clashes" in various places.

So the question:

Is there a way to "close" a namespace reference to get it back to my/global namespace or am I just totally misunderstanding the situation.

PS I should say I have an untidy personal project that is in its third incarnation. It needs a complete rewrite but, for now, I have to struggle on with thousands of lines of crappy code I wrote over the last two years.

PPS I have spent about an hour over several sessions trying to find an answer to this. I suspect I have not found an answer as I am getting completely the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: then rename the variable? $close should never equal Twilio\Rest\Client - what's your actual issue you're facing?

Comment: Lots of messy code mostly routed (if that is what I mean?) by file includes. I want to use a universal error catcher to send me texts/emails when the code fails. I would do that by including the error handler into the `helper.inc` file that is included with just about ALL active files. hence my worry.

Comment: The code should never fail in production.. that's what testing is for. Either way, there still shouldn't be any clashes ...

Comment: ... and children should be nice to their parents and people should pick up their litter. I am very aware that this little project is not being done as it "should" be but it's being done to the best of my ability, time and energy. This is a "private" project for now. It may become a public beta but that is a big maybe! It has zero security and some gnarly code but it is the best I can do for now. Yes I can stop for a year to rewrite it but that is not going to happen and in any case the code would still be pretty crappy given my time and ability. Just saying! Now can I "close" a namespace?

Comment: What .. that whole paragraph has no relevance to my comment. A namespace is completely different from a variable -what are your actual errors?

Comment: Something like `use Twilio\Rest\Client as TClient` if you've got a `Client` class already?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the actual problem is, but you can "get back to" the global namespace by using a backslash - such as `$client = new \MyGlobalClientClass();`

Comment: another possible option: don't use the `use` statement and instead prefix all the references when instantiating them: `$twilio = new \Twilio\Rest\Client()`

Comment: MER oh the  $twilio = new \Twilio\Rest\Client() sounds like a possible winner. @treyBake I am not getting any errors now I am just worried that I may create some. I have a Computer Sci degree from 1979 (!!!!) and did no programming for about 35-40 years and it ain't as easy as it used to be. Too many spliffs did not help either. OK I will go away and see if things fall over. It is just me looking at it for the moment anyhow. Thanks for the advice. (Oh I can only use one `@` which seems unfair!)

Comment: @BeNice That is definitely the safest way of doing things. And ah, I misunderstood you, I thought you meant you had errors :) and no such thing as too many ;) either way, I'd remove that comment before admins come along :)